# Équivalent to $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{2n}{k} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

Hollo 
Let $u_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{2n}{k} $ 
then after change indice and pascal relation we have

u_0=1 and.     $u_n = 4u_n -\frac{1}{n+1} \binom{2n}{n}$.

We remark.         u_n équivalent       (2/pi)*4^n

Comment: I voted to close because it is unclear what you are asking. What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

Note that $2u_n=4^n+{2n\choose n}$.

And ${2n\choose n}\sim\dfrac{4^n}{\sqrt{n\pi}}$ (easy to prove with [Wallis' integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis%27_integrals) or [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)), hence $u_n\sim 2^{2n-1}$.

Comment: Think you.     I am understand